# LINQ Error Invalid Column when retrieving additional column value

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, exception

I've got the following LINQ query.

```
    // Query the database
    IEnumerable<BestSeller> best_sellers = from bs in (db.smd_group)
                                           where bs.COMPANY == "SMD Textiles"
                                           where bs.DOCDATE > six_months_back
                                           where bs.CUSREF == customer.customer_ref
                                           group bs by bs.PRODCODE into g
                                           orderby g.Sum(x => x.MQTY) descending
                                           select new BestSeller()
                                           {
                                               product_code = g.Key.Trim(),
                                               total_quantity = Convert.ToString(g.Sum(x => x.MQTY)),
                                               // ERROR Occurs when the following line is removed
                                               //product_description = g.First().prd_prddes
                                           };

    // Get the top 25 products
    top25 = best_sellers.Take(25);
```

As you can see, I have commented out a line where my `BestSeller` objects are created.

I wish to set the `product_description` within my `BestSeller`object.  So I added the line `below:

```
product_description = g.First().prd_prddes
```

"prd_prddes" is the name of the column which holds our product description.

However, as soon as I add this line to my query I get a strange error:

> Invalid column name 'PRODCODE'.
>
> Invalid column name 'PRODCODE'.
>
> Invalid column name 'PRODCODE'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column
>   name 'PRODCODE'. Invalid column name 'PRODCODE'. Invalid column name
>   'PRODCODE'.

The column name PRODCODE clearly isn't invalid, because it works just fine if I remove the `product_description` line.

It's very peculiar...

Comment: How do you know `PRODCODE` "clearly isn't invalid"? I don't see it anywhere in your code (I see PRODCODE2), and I'm sure the code isn't lying when it throws that error... What type is `bs`?

Comment: Whoops, sorry I meant to change "PRODCODE2" back to "PRODCODE" before posting.  It isn't invalid, because without the line product_description = g.First().prd_prddes`, the code works and it returns all of the correct values.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like whatever you have in `g` doesn't have a column named `'PRODCODE'`

Personally, What I would do, is I'd just select `g` in your select statement, and then I'd make a break-point and use the debugger see what's in it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if all of your `PRODCODE` results are valid? It sounds like maybe one is null or empty. That would mean you can still group by it, but once you try to select it it's throwing that error.

Try this:

```
product_description = g.FirstOrDefault() == null 
    ? g.FirstOrDefault().prd_prddes  
    : "Empty";
```

If the first item is null, it will fall back and display "Empty". I'm not sure if the first item is null, though, so it may not work...